# Which C header defines the common variable names (PATH, HOME, IFS...)?

Tags: c, environment-variables, posix

[Chapter 8 of POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) define a list of commonly used environment variables "that are frequently exported by widely used command interpreters and applications".

However I cannot find any C header providing their names in any of my unix-like systems.

I'm looking for something like:

```
#define ENV_PATH "PATH"
#define ENV_USER "USER"
#define ENV_IFS "IFS"
...
```

Where I can find such header? Any OS-specific header would work: I just don't want to invent names for the constants myself.

**edit**

If you are used to only mainstream operating systems, you might ask: **why you want to use constants here? $PATH is always $PATH everywhere!**

This is not actually true.

In [Plan 9 from Bell Labs](http://man.cat-v.org/9front/1/rc), environment variables are usually lowercase (apparently due to [aesthetics](https://marc.info/?l=9fans&m=150825126207999&w=2)).

In [Jehanne](http://jehanne.io/), a new operating system derived by Plan 9, I'm reconsidering this design choice, to ease the integration of POSIX tools. However, since I like the lowercase environment variables, I'd like to be able to easily switch back to lowercase names when Jehanne will be "the one true operating system" :-D

Comment: There are no such standard header, neither in POSIX nor (especially) in C.

Comment: maybe try to get env variables name at the start of your programm? `void main(int ac, char **av, char **env)` then loop on Path, User and IFS ?!

Comment: Why would you want to type 2 more characters? PATH is always PATH. Changing it would never work, so there's no point in making it a define.

Comment: @Art edited to explain why this is not the case: in Plan9 for example, the list of directories to search for executables is named $path.

Comment: But Plan9 is not POSIX. POSIX requires `PATH` to be `PATH`, so it's no point in such header file.

Comment: BTW, the page you linked states that `path` on Plan9 is an array, whereas on Unix it's colon-separated string (and on Windows it's semicolon-separated string). So, simply `#defining` variable name wouldn't be sufficient, as semantics would still differ.

Comment: @el.pescado you might be surprised to know that neither Linux nor FreeBSD are fully compliant POSIX systems. Actually most non-posix systems use some POSIX style environment variable (even Windows has PATH). As for array vs string: it's trivially fixed with ~10 lines in rc code.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio But then neither `getenv("PATH")`, nor `getenv(MAGIC_LONG_STRING_ENDING_WITH_PATH)` will return you a path variable in a format that you expect. If you want portability to such systems you either need OS-dependent code that replaces the call to `getenv` with your own code or an emulated replacement for `getenv` that will return the data in a format you expect. And that loops back around to that such an emulated function wouldn't need special define.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio you're right about Linux and FreeBSD, but they at least try, so they're designed to be compatible, despite not being officially certified. Plan9 doesn't even try. That's not relevant, though. POSIX standard cited by you provides names of env variables as-is, so any `#define`s would be tautological.

Comment: BTW. How would you know names of defined constants? They could be `ENV_PATH`, `env_path`, `ENV_path` and so on... ;)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, there is no header file that provides any POSIX-specified list of environment variables used by applications and utilities.

A list of "certain variables that are frequently exported by widely used command interpreters and applications" [can be found at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08).  (The actual environment variable list requires reformatting but here it is anyway...)

> It is unwise to conflict with certain variables that are frequently
>   exported by widely used command interpreters and applications:
>
> ```
> ARFLAGS   IFS MAILPATH    PS1
> CC    LANG    MAILRC  PS2
> CDPATH    LC_ALL  MAKEFLAGS   PS3
> CFLAGS    LC_COLLATE  MAKESHELL   PS4
> CHARSET   LC_CTYPE    MANPATH PWD
> COLUMNS   LC_MESSAGES MBOX    RANDOM
> DATEMSK   LC_MONETARY MORE    SECONDS
> DEAD  LC_NUMERIC  MSGVERB SHELL
> EDITOR    LC_TIME NLSPATH TERM
> ENV   LDFLAGS NPROC   TERMCAP
> EXINIT    LEX OLDPWD  TERMINFO
> FC    LFLAGS  OPTARG  TMPDIR
> FCEDIT    LINENO  OPTERR  TZ
> FFLAGS    LINES   OPTIND  USER
> GET   LISTER  PAGER   VISUAL
> GFLAGS    LOGNAME PATH    YACC
> HISTFILE  LPDEST  PPID    YFLAGS
> HISTORY   MAIL    PRINTER  
> HISTSIZE  MAILCHECK   PROCLANG     
> HOME  MAILER  PROJECTDIR
> ```

To access the value of an environment variable, [use the `getenv()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getenv.html).

The [`exec()` function documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) specifies the `char **environ` variable:

> In addition, the following variable, which must be declared by the
>   user if it is to be used directly:
>
> ```
> extern char **environ;
> ```
>
> is initialized as a pointer to an array of character pointers to the
>   environment strings. The argv and environ arrays are each terminated
>   by a null pointer. . The null pointer terminating the `argv` array is not counted in `argc`.
>
> Applications can change the entire environment in a single operation
>   by assigning the `environ` variable to point to an array of character
>   pointers to the new environment strings. After assigning a new value
>   to `environ`, applications should not rely on the new environment
>   strings remaining part of the environment, as a call to `getenv()`,
>    `putenv()`, `setenv()`, `unsetenv()`, or
>   any function that is dependent on an environment variable may, on
>   noticing that `environ` has changed, copy the environment strings to a
>   new array and assign `environ` to point to it.
>
> Any application that directly modifies the pointers to which the
>   `environ` variable points has undefined behavior.
>
> Conforming multi-threaded applications shall not use the `environ`
>   variable to access or modify any environment variable while any other
>   thread is concurrently modifying any environment variable. A call to
>   any function dependent on any environment variable shall be considered
>   a use of the `environ` variable to access that environment variable.

Comment: Only the first sentence provide an answer here. The rest is quoting a document already linked in the question...

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like that and in get_env_variables function you modify what you want. Just create something like a strncmp function for check if you want to modify this variable or not.

```
int main(int ac, char **av, char **env){
  int i = 0;

  while (env[i] != NULL){
   env[i] = get_env_variables(env[i]);
   i++;
  }
}

char *get_env_variables(char *str) {
  // PUT SOME CODE HERE
}
```

**EDIT : don't forgot to return new env[i].**